# Can't Run simple program Opencv 3.1 with Eclipse (Linking error)

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I am configuring openCV on my eclipse and can't run the simple example given in the openCV tutorial, i followed the exact steps as in [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html)

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  Mat image;
  image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

  if( argc != 2 || !image.data )
    {
      printf( "No image data \n" );
      return -1;
    }

  namedWindow( "Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Display Image", image );

  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

The project settings are 
[image: includes]

[image: library]

It gives me the following errors:

- cannot find -lopencv_contrib     C/C++ Problem
- make: *** [projectname] Error 1              C/C++ Problem
- recipe for target 'projectname' failed   makefile    /faa/Debug  line
  45   C/C++ Problem

When i removed `opencv_contrib` the errors become:

- ./src/projectname.o: undefined reference to symbol
  '_ZN2cv6imreadERKNS_6StringEi'       C/C++ Problem
- make: *** [projectname] Error 1          C/C++ Problem
- recipe for target 'projectname' failed   makefile    /projectname/Debug  line 45 C/C++ Problem

Comment: Your problem is with your project settings not with the code.

Comment: @drescherjm i added snapshots for the settings.

Comment: @Misaki -- is that library in `/usr/local/lib`? Question is why you're even linking with most of those libs, as the source code you show doesn't make use of anything from those modules.

Comment: @DanMašek -- I typed `pkg-config --cflags opencv` in the terminal and the output was this directory so i used it. It does't matter now that i don't use them,  i just want a simple code to run to make sure that opencv is working.

Comment: Are the binaries of **opencv_contrib** in that directory? The possible answers being "Yes, I checked and there are files named _<list of filenames>_." or "No, I looked, but there's nothing even remotely close to that name."

Comment: @DanMašek -- no there is not, i removed it from the project's library and now the errors are
./src/projectname.o: undefined reference to symbol _ZN2cv6imreadERKNS_6StringEi'   
and the #2 and #3 from the question.

Comment: How did you install OpenCV? Which version was it? Which compiler are you using and on which platform? BTW, note that your title mentions OpenCV 3, but you refer to documentation from 2.4.x -- might not be an issue in this specific case, but there are some differences which might catch you by surprise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the opencv and reinstalled it again but this time i used `Debug` instead of `Release` in

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

and it worked.